# How to prevent a non-empty host folder from overriding a mounted container folder?

Tags: node.js, laravel, docker, npm

I am trying to compile my assets using Docker for a Laravel project.

So, I have created a service called npm which is built from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as node

WORKDIR /usr/src

ADD ./resources ./resources
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "vite.config.js", "./"]

RUN npm install --global cross-env
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

Also, I am using the following Docker-compose configuration

```
  node:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./services/nodejs/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    container_name: "nodejs"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - php
```

Although the service is built successfully, it seems that my host directory (which is non-empty) is overriding the content of my node container. So, eventually I end up with no "node_modules" directory and my compiled assets and resources get lost.

So, what should I do?
I think that I can first copy the content of my host folder to the container, then delete the content of my host folder, and then run my scripts and then copy it back. But that seems to be a very time consuming thing to do. What is the best practice for cases like this? I'm sure I'm not the first one that has dockerized a full-stack Laravel project. Thanks in advance

Comment: you are using a volume as `./:/var/www` which basically does what you don't want

Comment: You're using a volume so this is for your dev environment. You then don't need node_modules in your container - just build it normally

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, exactly. The reason I'm doing that is because I want folders from my node container to get copied back to my host machine. I mean I have to somehow copy "node_modules" and "resources" folders from my node container to my host machine and I can't see how I could do that.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible within the Dockerfile (and I do think this may be abuse of containers). You can copy from the container to the host using `docker cp`

Comment: @BenGooding But is it different in production really? I mean even in production, first I have to pull my code from the repository, and then run docker-compose up. No? So, I can't see how the outcome will be different.

Comment: @apokryfos Could you please explain why that would be an abuse of containers? I mean even my problem doesn't get solved, I could still learn more about Docker and containers.

Comment: For developement the container does not have the responsibility of building your code, mainly because while developing it's very inconvinient to rebuilding the container whenever you make any code changes so we use the volume as you have there so the container serves the source files from your host filesystem. Typically you'd also run an `npm run watch` or something like that so code changes are picked up and reflected instantly

Comment: For production you would not use a volume, and copy the source to the container and then build it in the container like you are doing now but you would not need to copy it back to the host. The docker image you end up with will be what you need to run your application on a docker host (any docker host actually)

Comment: @apokryfos OK. I get it now. So, basically for production, I should do "git pull" in my Dockerfile and then do the rest. Am I right?

Comment: personally I do the pull outside the container and then copy the files to the container before doing that, and the reason I do that is because `git` is not typically installed in containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you `COPY` your application code into the container.  That leaves you in a position where you need to bind-mount things in, but since the host directory is missing some built parts, the final container image is incomplete.

There's an especially important detail here around using this container as part of your build sequence which I'll get back to.

The first thing to do is to make sure all of the things you need are in the image itself.

```bash
FROM node:16-alpine as node
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN npm install --global cross-env

# run `npm install` first to avoid rebuilds if `package.json` is unchanged
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "vite.config.js", "./"]
RUN npm install

# then copy in the rest of the application
# (make sure `node_modules` and `build` are in `.dockerignore`)
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build

# and explain how to run the container (*)
CMD npm run start
```

Then in your `docker-compose.yml` file, you don't need to specify `volumes:` because the code is already in your image.  You similarly don't need to declare a `working_dir:` because the Dockerfile sets `WORKDIR` already.  This section of your Compose file can probably be trimmed down to

```yaml
  node:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./services/nodejs/Dockerfile
    tty: true    # actually needed?
    depends_on:
      - php
```

I don't think you actually want this container, though, since

> I am trying to compile my assets using Docker for a Laravel project.

In this case you can use this Dockerfile (and it must be the complete self-contained Dockerfile) as part of a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).  Put this Dockerfile at the start of your PHP application Dockerfile and give it a name, and then you can `COPY` the built assets from one stage to another.

```bash
FROM node:16-alpine AS node # <-- `AS somename` is important
...
RUN npm run build
# no specific need for a CMD here

FROM php:fpm
...
COPY --from=node /usr/src/build ./static/
```

Again, since this will get filled in at Docker image build time, it's important to not overwrite the image content with a `volumes:` mount.

If you do this then there's not a "Node container" at all, and you can just outright remove this from your `docker-compose.yml` file.  For this setup you don't need a long-running server, you just need to have Node available to run a compilation step at build time, and including it in a Dockerfile stage is enough for that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I wish I could upvote your answer, but I can't because of my low reputation. Anyway, I still can't help but wonder why Docker allows only one-way synchronization right after building. I mean if my container has something after build that is missing in my host and I have mounted it as a volume, it's only natural to assume that it will be transferred to my host instead of my host overriding it but it seems that is seen as bad practice and I'm not supposed to use Docker like that.